# On-topic? Does Unicode have a symbol for synchronization (2 arrows following each other in a circle)?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

> I want to know whether Unicode has a symbol for synchronization, which
>   is usually two arrows following each other in a circle. These
>   symbols ↷⎋⇄⟲☯♻ are the closest I could find. Not found on http://shapecatcher.com

I am afraid the question will be closed per [Let's play the guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), even though I believe it would be searchable, and thus useful to many other people.

So, on-topic, off-topic, better on another site, or a plainly bad question?

*Stack Overflow has [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384380/is-there-a-unicode-glyph-that-looks-like-a-key-icon) but is [not welcoming them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168876).*

---

UPDATE: Posted [Unicode character that conveys 'synchronization'?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/unicode-character-that-conveys-synchronization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't consider either on-topic or off-topic. It is very specific, and it can have an element of opinion, but I think it's still valid and might of help for other people.

I would however rephrase it more in the lines of

> Is there a Unicode character consisting of two arrows in a circle, or
>   similar character that could convey 'synchronization'?

Very similar to John's suggestion, but focusing more on the graphics rather than the possible 'subjective' elements.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider this off topic, though I might word it slightly different:

> Which Unicode character can be used to convey 'synchronization'?

This way it's less of a yes or no question and more of a subjective question. A similar question was asked about a year ago: [What symbol indicates a reference to another page?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7164/what-symbol-indicates-a-reference-to-another-page)

As a side-note: some of those characters don't show up for me: [image] (Chrome/Windows 7)